Alternative proof (more geometric?) of packing statement, Exercise 3, Section 13.1 in Matousek
The following (rephrased) exercise is given on page 315 of Matousek's book [1].

Fix $n \geq 1$ and let $\mathscr{X} \subset \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be $\sqrt{2}$-separated, so that
$$
\|x - y\|_2 \geq \sqrt{2} \quad \mbox{for all distinct}~x, y \in \mathscr{X}.
$$
Show that the cardinality satisfies $|\mathscr{X}| \leq 2n$.

Above, $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the standard Euclidean norm and $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the unit sphere.
Here's my approach to a solution.

Solution: We note the separation condition, is equivalent to
$$
\langle x, y \rangle \leq 0, \quad \mbox{for all  distinct}~ x, y \in \mathscr{X}.
$$
Now, induct on the dimension. The claim is obvious when $n = 1$. For $n > 1$, fix $x \in \mathscr{X}$ and partition $\mathscr{X}$ as $$\mathscr{X} = \mathscr{Y} \cup \{x\}, \quad \mbox{and} \quad \mathscr{Y} = \mathscr{Y}_0 \cup\mathscr{Y}_<.$$
Here we split $\mathscr{X}$ into $x$ and its complement, $\mathscr{Y}$, which is further split into the part with strictly negative (resp., 0) inner product with $x$, given by $\mathscr{Y}_{<}$ (resp., $\mathscr{Y}_0$). Consider the projection, $\pi(u) = u - \langle u, x \rangle x$. We claim that
$$
\pi(y) \neq \pi(y') \quad \mbox{for any distinct}~y, y' \in \mathscr{Y}.
$$
This obviously holds for $y, y' \in \mathscr{Y}_0$. If $y, y' \in \mathscr{Y}_<$, then
$$
0 \geq \langle y, y' \rangle = \langle y, x \rangle \langle y', x\rangle  + \langle \pi(y), \pi(y') \rangle > \langle \pi(y), \pi(y') \rangle,
$$
implying $\pi(y) \neq \pi(y')$. If $y \in \mathscr{Y}_0, y' \in \mathscr{Y}_<$, then similarly, $\langle \pi(y), \pi(y')\rangle \leq 0$, which implies $\pi(y) \neq \pi(y')$ (otherwise $y = \pm x$).  Finally, set $\mathscr{Y}_{<, \neq} = \mathscr{Y}_< \setminus \mathrm{ker}(\pi)$. Then the collection
$$
\mathscr{X'} = \pi(\mathscr{Y}_{0}) \cup 
\Big\{\, \frac{\pi(y)}{\| \pi(y) \|_2} : y \in \mathscr{Y}_{<, \neq} \,\Big \} 
$$
is (the image of) a set of vectors in $\mathbb{S}^{n-2}$ with pairwise nonpositive inner product. Induction yields
$$
|\mathscr{Y}_{<, \neq}| +  |\mathscr{Y}_0| = |\mathscr{X'}| \leq 2(n-1) = 2n-2. 
$$
Concluding, we find
$$
|\mathscr{X'}| = |\mathscr{Y}_<| + |\mathscr{Y_0}| + 1 
\leq (|\mathscr{Y}_{<, \neq}| + 1) + |\mathscr{Y}_0| + 1 \leq 2n.
$$

Although I think it is correct, I feel like it is maybe too complicated. I feel like there should be a more "geometric" proof that simply uses some observation that each time we add a point it requires the remaining points to lie in some (intersection of) halfspace(s) and there can't be too many of those.
[1] Matoušek, Jiří. Lectures on discrete geometry. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 212. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2002.
